# How to refresh environment variable process snapshot?

Tags: c#, windows

As you know if you start an `.exe` not obviously it makes env var snapshot. So, for example you have an env var `MY_ENV_VAR_FOO = hello`and your exe run and work with this var without any issues. But (for example) you need to change this env var value from `hello` to `hello_word` (without to close your .exe).

What problem is? You `.exe` has env var snapshot and don't know anything about that you updated the value.

In order to get new env var value you need to restart your `.exe`. You can make it in a few ways for example just close your `.exe` and open it again by hands or you can do it with help of script. **And my `.exe` has a logic that start this script**.

So, I wrote the script (because actually I don't have an direct access to close and open my `.exe`)

There is a script

```
set MY_TARGET=C:\My_program

taskkill /IM My_program.exe /F

@echo off
if %errorlevel% NEQ 0  echo ERROR!!! & goto :exit
@echo on

timeout 10

start "" %MY_TARGET%\My_program.exe

:exit
```

What script are doing is close the `.exe` and after 10 sec open it again.

So, it looks like restart for `.exe` was done, but issue is that each new process kind of inherit env vars from process which start it...

It is means that (as I told above that my `.exe` has a logic to start script) my `.exe` has env vars snapshot, script is starting and take snapshot from my `.exe`, then script my `.exe` and after 10 sec start it again, but when script starts `.exe`, `.exe` again take env var snapshot from who start him -> script, but script has the same (without update) env vars...

So, question is - is there a way how to refresh env vars? May there is a kind on line that I need to add to scrip like - `refresh_env_vars_command` between close the `.exe` and open it again?

Answer (score 0):

Read up on `WM_SETTINGCHANGE`. Windows notifies all top level windows when the env variables change.

If your app is a console one without a message loop, you might have to create an invisible window on a worker thread just to catch that message. Then you'd have to communicate the env var change event back to the main thread.

Comment: As far as I understand `windows notifies` it means kind of callback, where I can get new value, but I am not sure that it can help, because ok I get in callback new value but actually in env var snapshot it old one... And if for example from my `.exe` I need to open another `.exe`, so this another `.exe` will not know nothing about new value that my "father" `.exe` got in callback, right?

Comment: You can propagate the new value to your process' snapshot with `setenv`. This way, the snapshot will always be in sync with the systemwide values. And created processes will inherit it.